# How do I prioritize first word matches and not first characters in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

**TLDR:** I want `Game of thrones` before `Gamer` if I search for `Game`.

Ok, so below is my ES query for an index filled with movie titles. I want to prioritize matches in the beginning of the string, which I *think* I have done.

E.g: `Gamer` gets a higher score than `End Game` if my search term is `game`.

But I really want it to prioritize exact **first** **word** matches and not first characters... if that's the correct way to describe this problem. I would like this to happen:
`Game of thrones` before `Gamer` and than lastly `End Game`.

Anyone got any idea how to do this?

This is my current query:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "game",
            "type": "phrase_prefix",
            "max_expansions": 20,
            "fields": [
              "titleName.title^10",
              "titleDescription.displayed",
              "titleDescription.short"
            ],
            "boost": 1.5
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "fuzziness": "AUTO",
            "query": "game",
            "fields": [
              "titleName.title^10",
              "titleDescription.displayed",
              "titleDescription.short"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is the mapping of your index?

Comment: To me it sounds like you want to favor matches that happen at the start of the searched text... basically, the closer to position 0 the better. In this case, I think you may need a custom script that looks at [the offset of the term within the document field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/modules-scripting-engine.html). You will also need to enable an [index_option that indexes offsets](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/index-options.html). After you do this, you just need to add another statement to your `should` list of queries.

Comment: "... favor matches that happen at the start of the searched text" Isn't this what the first should with the type `phrase_prefix`? Image of my mapping is here: https://ibb.co/VHTWknZ.